# How to parse a string and replace certain characters of a string?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I want to parse a string and replace certain characters in that string I tried using a delimiter but it didn't work correctly.

This is the string I want to parse:

```
chartData = [T44E-7    | x   |G-7    | x   |
Bb^7    | x   |Bh7    |E7#9    |A-7    | x   |F#h7    | x   |F-7    | x Q  |C-7    | x   |B7#9    | x  Z        Y{QC-7    | x   |Ab^7    | x  }
```

And this is the end result I want:

```
[T44E-7    | x   |G-7    | x   |

|  Bb^7    | x   |Bh7    |E7#9 |

|A-7       | x   |F#h7   | x   |

|F-7       | x Q |C-7    | x   |

|B7#9      | x   ||        

|:QC-7     | x   |Ab^7    | x  :|
```

I also want to replace x with %, Z with ||, { with |: and } with :|.

Here is a parse function that I have:

```
void parseChartData(string chartDataString){
    string token;
    if(!chartDataString.empty()){ 
         chartData.clear();
         chartData.append(chartDataString);
         string delimiter = "|";
         int pos = 0;
         while ((pos = chartData.find(delimiter)) != pos) {
             token = chartData.substr(0,pos);
             cout << token << endl;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how to parse a a string so I can only show 4 bars per line

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I think is this one.

```
int occurrencies = 0;    // number of "|" found
int curPos = 0;
int startPos = 0;
string delimiter = "|";
// find the next delimiter from the last one found, not from the beginning of chartData
while ((pos = chartData.find(delimiter, curPos)) != string::npos) {
    curPos = pos+1;
    occurrencies++;

    // print something only if 4 delimiters have been found
    if (occurrencies%4 == 0) {
        // print the part from the last character printed to the last delimiter found
        string part = chartData.substr(startPos,pos-startPos);
        cout<<part<<endl;
        // after printing, the last character printed become the beginning of the next token
        startPos = pos+1;
    }
}

// at the end print the remaining part of chartData
string lastPart = chartData.substr(startPos,string.size()-startPos);
cout<<lastPart<<endl;
```

It should work

Comment: Just change "curPos = pos;" in "curPos = pos+1;". The infine loop is because it always find the same character. The same thing for "startPos = pos", which become "startPos = pos+1".